# define javascript variable as a pointer, when change the pointer, the target changed?

Tags: javascript, pointers, variables

I come across some wired code when I was learning the Vue Dependency Tracking:

```js
function convert(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      let internalValue = obj[key]
      Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        get() {
          console.log(`getting key "${key}": ${internalValue}`)
          return internalValue
        },
        set(newValue) {
          console.log(`setting key "${key}" to: ${newValue}`)
          internalValue = newValue
          console.log(obj);
        }
      })
    })
    return obj
  }

// test
let o = {a: 'hello',b:'world'};
let convO = convert(o);
convO.b = 'javascript';
// in normal condition, change a pointer won't change the target:
let p = o['b'];
p = 'woola'
console.log('normal condition', o);
```

Inside the `forEach` callback function, we firstly define a variable `internalValue` as a pointer, which point to `obj[key]`. Secondly, we changed that pointer. Why the pointed target is mutated? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: By the way, the so called "pointer" here is just a reference technically, it just some space in the memory which reference to the target's address.